# The unmanaged memory leak of the w3wp process of the .net5 program, where is the memory occupied?

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-leaks, windbg, .net-5

I encountered a strange problem when analyzing memory leaks in windbg... Memory was lost...

1. `!address -summary` shows MEM_COMMIT = 3.3G

```
0:048> !address -summary

                                     
Mapping file section regions...
Mapping module regions...
Mapping PEB regions...
Mapping TEB and stack regions...
Mapping heap regions...
Mapping page heap regions...
Mapping other regions...
Mapping stack trace database regions...
Mapping activation context regions...

--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                    447     7df8`acd2e000 ( 125.971 TB)           98.42%
<unknown>                              1688      207`19afc000 (   2.028 TB)  99.96%    1.58%
Stack                                   234        0`18260000 ( 386.375 MB)   0.02%    0.00%
Heap                                    120        0`168ec000 ( 360.922 MB)   0.02%    0.00%
Image                                  1856        0`0aa00000 ( 170.000 MB)   0.01%    0.00%
Other                                    11        0`001dd000 (   1.863 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
TEB                                      78        0`0009c000 ( 624.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_MAPPED                              387      200`03a66000 (   2.000 TB)  98.59%    1.56%
MEM_PRIVATE                            1745        7`44e5c000 (  29.077 GB)   1.40%    0.02%
MEM_IMAGE                              1856        0`0aa00000 ( 170.000 MB)   0.01%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                447     7df8`acd2e000 ( 125.971 TB)           98.42%
MEM_RESERVE                             631      206`7d08b000 (   2.025 TB)  99.84%    1.58%
MEM_COMMIT                             3357        0`d6237000 (   3.346 GB)   0.16%    0.00%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_READWRITE                         1587        0`c52ee000 (   3.081 GB)   0.15%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                          1147        0`0816b000 ( 129.418 MB)   0.01%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                       312        0`05f0a000 (  95.039 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                   57        0`019a1000 (  25.629 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_NOACCESS                           129        0`013d8000 (  19.844 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD                78        0`000ec000 ( 944.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                           47        0`0006f000 ( 444.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                    1c6`45d8f000     7c2e`42281000 ( 124.181 TB)
<unknown>                              7dfc`a2a6d000      1f8`bfa04000 (   1.972 TB)
Stack                                    45`800c0000        0`0104b000 (  16.293 MB)
Heap                                    1c6`3636f000        0`07d01000 ( 125.004 MB)
Image                                  7ffa`bafbf000        0`00e7a000 (  14.477 MB)
Other                                   1c0`05d40000        0`00181000 (   1.504 MB)
TEB                                      45`f68b0000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kB)
PEB                                      45`f6939000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kB)
```

2. `!eeheap` shows the total memory of the heap 900M。[gc (798M) + loader(132M) ]

```
0:048> !eeheap 
Loader Heap:
--------------------------------------
System Domain:     00007ffa7929d0a0
...
Module 00007ffa1e71d6a0: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Module 00007ffa1ec8da48: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Module 00007ffa1ee3cb18: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Module 00007ffa1f439618: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Total size:      Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
--------------------------------------
Total LoaderHeap size:   Size: 0x7dfd000 (132108288) bytes total, 0x2d4000 (2965504) bytes wasted.
=======================================
Number of GC Heaps: 16
------------------------------
Heap 0 (000001C0069F7AE0)
...
Heap 15 (000001C006E01BA0)
generation 0 starts at 0x000001C5A7770600
generation 1 starts at 0x000001C5A776B898
generation 2 starts at 0x000001C5A7121000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001C5A7120000  000001C5A7121000  000001C5A883B790  0x171a790(24225680)
Large object heap starts at 0x000001C5E7121000
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001C5E7120000  000001C5E7121000  000001C5E774D1E0  0x62c1e0(6472160)
Pinned object heap starts at 0x000001C5F7121000
000001C5F7120000  000001C5F7121000  000001C5F7390EF8  0x26fef8(2555640)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x1fb6868 (33253480) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:    Size: 0x2f9480a0 (798261408) bytes.
```

3. `!eeheap -s` shows 68M of unmanaged memory

```
0:048> !heap -s


************************************************************************************************************************
                                              NT HEAP STATS BELOW
************************************************************************************************************************
LFH Key                   : 0x741d83161cb41a46
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
          Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                            (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
000001c0057d0000 00000002   97696  68108  97304  10566   686    18    7     51   LFH
    External fragmentation  15 % (686 free blocks)
000001c005750000 00008000      64      4     64      2     1     1    0      0      
000001c005b30000 00001002    3516   2564   3124    116    43     3    0      1   LFH
000001c006790000 00001002      60      8     60      5     1     1    0      0      
000001c006740000 00001003      60      8     60      6     1     1    0    N/A   
000001c007030000 00001002    1472    156   1080      2    14     2    0      0   LFH
000001c007110000 00041002      60      8     60      5     1     1    0      0      
000001c617d60000 00041002     452     24     60      0     2     1    0      0   LFH
000001c616060000 00001002    1472    216   1080     22    11     2    0      0   LFH
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Conclusion: gc heap(798M) + loader heap(132M) + unmanged heap(68M) is much smaller than 3.3G of process memory.

Where did my remaining memory of about 2G go? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Use DebugDiag leak track component to analyze first, https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2008/02/19/high-memory-usage-with-usercontrols-in-ie-using-debug-diag.html

Comment: @Lex Li Because in the closed environment of production, only post-debugging can be done, thank you for leaving a message

Comment: With post-debugging you cannot quickly locate the culprit. Open a support case with Microsoft support and they can give a detailed action plan on how to properly set up the tools in production environment (even banks and governments allow certain tools in production).

Answer (score 0):

what are you looking for in the dump if you want to know the details of MEM_COMMIT

you can issue  **!address -f:MEM_COMMIT**

use .logopen x:\foo.ext  and log the results to a file
as the resulting output maybe large

here is a verification of summary mem_commit size versus filtered mem_commit size

```
0:000> .shell -ci "!address -summary" grep -i mem_COMMIT
MEM_COMMIT                              155        0`02f3d000 (  **47.238 MB**)   0.00%    0.00%
.shell: Process exited


0:000> r$t0=0;!address -f:MEM_COMMIT -c:"r $t0 = @$t0+%3";?? @$t0/1048576.0

double **47.23828125**
0:000>
```

Comment: This is a good way, thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 0):

```
 798 MB GC Heap      (as mentioned by you)
 132 MB Loader Heap  (as mentioned by you)
  68 MB Native Heap  (as mentioned by you)
 >15 MB Stacks (at 64kB each, for 234 Stacks)
 170 MB Image (DLLs that are loaded)
-------
1183 MB
```

The rest is probably native heap as well, but with allocations > 512 kB, so they are not handled by the heap manager any more but will be treated like VirtualAlloc() calls and thus fall into the `<unknown>` category.

Comment: I just read some documents and I found that `VirtualAlloc` is more low-level than `HeapAlloc`. My program sdk may directly use VirtualAlloc to allocate memory, and `heap -s` only counts the memory of heapalloc. I should understand, right, thank you for your reply, thank you very much！

Comment: @dotnetfly: Yes, you SDK may use VirtualAlloc directly. That's one aspect. VirtualAlloc will only give memory in 65536 B blocks. The heap manager provides additional granularity in order to not waste 65532 B if you allocated 4 B on the heap. If you allocate 512 kB via HeapAlloc, there's not much benefit of dealing with the remaining bytes, thus HeapAlloc directly gives you the memory without building the heap structures around it.